Updating the database with null values while preserving the values in other columns
I am working on a REST API. At the moment I've been creating a PATCH endpoint to update user information such as their username, birthday, etc. I've been stuck for a couple days trying to make updating the information work with my Postgres database.
I am using Bun ORM https://bun.uptrace.dev/guide/query-update.html to interact with the database. The issues I've been having stem from this code snippet below:
/* Database Model */
type User struct {
    Id             uuid.UUID `json:"id,omitempty" bun:"column:pk,type:uuid,default:gen_random_uuid()"`
    Email          string    `json:"email,omitempty"`
    Name           string    `json:"name,omitempty"`
    Username       string    `json:"username,omitempty"`
    Password       string    `json:"-" dbKey:"password"`
    Verified       bool      `json:"verified,omitempty"`
    EmailVerified  bool      `json:"emailVerified,omitempty"`
    Avatar         *string   `json:"avatar,omitempty"`
    GraduationYear int       `json:"graduationYear,omitempty"`
    Degree         *string   `json:"degree,omitempty"`
    Major          *string   `json:"major,omitempty"`
    Intrests       int       `json:"intrests,omitempty"`
    Clubs          int       `json:"clubs,omitempty"`
    Sports         int       `json:"sports,omitempty"`
    NotificationId string    `json:"notificationId,omitempty"`
    CreatedAt      time.Time `json:"createdAt,omitempty" bun:"type:timestamp,default:now()"`
    UpdatedAt      time.Time `json:"updatedAt,omitempty" bun:"type:timestamp,default:now()"`
}

func (r *userRepositoryImpl) UpdateUser(userId string, data models.User) (*models.User, error) {
    user := models.User(data)

    _, err := r.db.NewUpdate().Model(&user).Where("id = ?", userId).Returning("*").Exec(r.context)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return &user, nil
}

This function is meant to update the user depending on what data I give the User struct. However, if I want to update only ONE of the fields, it sets all of the columns in my Postgres database to their default or zero value. Example:
/* This resets all other column values to their default or zero value, just affecting the avatar column */
updatedUser, err := s.userRepository.UpdateUser(userId, models.User{
    Avatar: &avatarUrl,
})


I later came across this method in Bun ORM: Omit Zero Values. This allowed me to update the avatar column only, and the ORM ignored the empty fields in the struct. But then I cannot reset the avatar column back to an empty string, cause it will be ignored.
I have tried several things, most likely really over-engineered. I even tried reflection since I got desperate.

Tried converting the User struct fields that weren't empty to a map[string]interface{}, and passing that to the Model method. Unfortunately the ORM did not convert my types to how they were defined in my User struct since I used a map.
I tried merging the old struct with a struct containing the data I wanted to update, which worked at first but was extremely hacky and I wouldn't prefer to use that as a solution.
I tried using pointer values like *string to represent null values, but just got the same result as I described at the beginning of my post.

I would really appreciate some guidance and help with this, part of me feels like I'm over thinking it, and I would like to hear others thoughts. If extra clarification is needed, Ill edit this post as necessary.
Edit 1
/* The request structure that the endpoint can receive. Certain fields may be excluded, since its a PATCH request */
type UpdateDataRequest struct {
    Email          string `json:"email,omitempty" validate:"omitempty,email"`
    Name           string `json:"name,omitempty" validate:"omitempty,min=3,max=32"`
    Username       string `json:"username,omitempty" validate:"omitempty,min=3,max=24"`
    GraduationYear int    `json:"graduationYear,omitempty" validate:"omitempty,number"`
    Degree         string `json:"degree,omitempty" validate:"omitempty,min=3,max=32"`
    Major          string `json:"major,omitempty" validate:"omitempty,min=3,max=32"`
    Intrests       int    `json:"intrests,omitempty" validate:"omitempty,number"`
    Clubs          int    `json:"clubs,omitempty" validate:"omitempty,number"`
    Sports         int    `json:"sports,omitempty" validate:"omitempty,number"`
}


/* Updates the user (From my PATCH enddpoint) */
updatedUser, err := s.userRepository.UpdateUser(userId, models.User{
    Email:          updateUserData.Email,
    Name:           updateUserData.Name,
    Username:       updateUserData.Username,
    GraduationYear: updateUserData.GraduationYear,
    Degree:         &updateUserData.Degree,
    Major:          &updateUserData.Major,
    Intrests:       updateUserData.Intrests,
    Clubs:          updateUserData.Clubs,
    Sports:         updateUserData.Sports,
    UpdatedAt:      time.Now(),
})


you can use db.Exec() method to update only some columns. the docs: [https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/uptrace/bun#UpdateQuery]

@ABDULLOKHMUKHAMMADJONOV Yea, I would like to be able update the data when I specify it in the struct if possible. Ill look into it further though.

The fact this simple operation is failing and requires this much work is an indication you should be looking for another way of interacting with the database.

I think what you are looking for, if you haven't found it already, is using something like the following. If you break it down you could conditionally add values to the UpdateQuery object returned by Model(yourModel) instead of using method chaining.
db.NewUpdate().
  Model(yourModel).
  Set("colName ? ", theUpdatedValue).
  Set("otherColName ? ", otherUpdatedValue).
  ... more Set(..)...
  Where("yourRow.id = ?", rowId).
  Exec(.....etc...)

as per the docs [https://bun.uptrace.dev/guide/query-update.html#example]
